# Are there any circular references in Stack Overflow database scheme?

Tags: discussion

Last days I have been thinking if circular references are acceptable in database design or not. I have come to a conclusion that I will try to keep for the future. Nevertheless, I would still be interested what an approach of SO team is to get a different perspective  in this aspect.

Comment: Just a tiny question; what are you trying to accomplish with your numerous, minor edits? They aren't improving the question.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Sorry for the edits.

Comment: No problem, @clime. Just wondering :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I just wanted to make my question more to the point.

Answer (score 6):

Well, our posts table is used for both questions and answers, so answers reference questions *in the same table* (via a parent id), and: for performance (this is redundant data that could be reproduced separately), the same posts table has an "accepted answer" field, which goes back from a question to an answer... so yes: we have some circular references. Because the *thing we are modelling* has circular references. So: "yes", but also: this knowledge is meaningless and should not be used to mean, imply, suggest or hint at what is appropriate for *your* scenario without a lot of extra context, which frankly would be off-topic here (and most places).

Comment: Self-referencing (reflexive) circular refenreces are of course totally  alright. I should have mention I mean circular references between different models...

Comment: @clime I suspect we will then devolve into a discussion about what constitutes a different model. Basically, the short version is that we're brutally pragmatic. We are not purists. We are not virginal angels. We do ugly stuff that works well, and works fast - and we'll face the maintenance costs head on with our heads held high. We optimize for performance, and work with a "move fast and break stuff" approach.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I have realized that the circular reference you mention is exactly the circular reference I had in mind even though it is on the same table. The alternative was to give an attribute "accepted" (true/false) to an answer (+partial unique index on (parent_id, accepted=True) to ensure there is at most one accepted answer). I wonder how you check that the accepted answer must point to a domain of question's answers. If on db level or an application level.

Comment: @MarcGravell By the way, when you search for an accepted answer of a post, I suspect the solution I suggest is faster. The partial unique index is going to contain only nodes for the accepted answers. With that attribute "acceptedAnswerId" you probably search on the Post's primary key, which means that you search on index that contains all the posts. The difference might be more significant e.g. if you want to fetch all the answers of some user and mark the accepted ones. With the "accepted" attribute this would be easy. I can't quite imagine how to do it fast with acceptedAnswerId.

Comment: "We are not virginal angels". I'm sad.

Comment: "Move fast and break stuff" It's a shame that so many low-rep SO contributors are also learning this harmful tactic.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/219343/db-design-circular-references-for-the-one-of-many-case/219823#219823